# Java : Index out of bound exception when creating a string with no matching consecutive characters

Tags: java, string

This is my function which takes a string as input for example `aabbaaa`. I am deleting the character if the next one to it is the same. In this way I am removing consecutive occurrences of a character i.e the string will become `aba`. But it is throwing me `indexoutofbounds exception`.

```
static int alternatingCharacters(String s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
        {
            while (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1) && i+1<sb.length())
            {
                sb=sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: sb.charAt(i+1) && i+1<sb.length() in java stuff in ifs is executed left to right, so it first attempts to take i+1 char.

Comment: I doubt this compiles with the `println` after the `return`...

Comment: @Worthless means turn both sides of `&&` around so that `charAt(i+1)` is safe.

Comment: `return s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");`

Comment: Thanks man it worked well. Never though this would be the mistake. i was thinking about other complex things but not this simple mistake.

Comment: @Worthless Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the exception, this is a very inefficient way to delete chars from the string.

Every time you invoke `sb.deleteCharAt(i)`, it has to shift all of the characters to the right of `i` along by 1. In the worst case, this has quadratic time complexity.

Instead, it is much more efficient simply to move the characters, and then trim the end:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
  int len = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); ++i) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) != sb.charAt(len - 1)) {
      sb.setCharAt(len++, sb.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  sb.setLength(len);
}
```

This has linear time complexity.

You can do it a little more directly, too, by operating directly on a `char[]`:

```
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
  char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
  int len = 1; // Start at 1, since the first character isn't equal to the one before it.
  for (int i = 1; i < cs.length; ++i) {
    if (cs[i] != cs[len-1]) {
      cs[len++] = cs[i];
    }
  }
  s = new String(cs, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are iterating till `sb.length()` and then inside the loop in the `while` condition you are using :

```
while (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1) && i+1<sb.length())
```

And the sentence `sb.charAt(i+1)` is what icauses the `IndexOutOfBoundException` because there's no such index in the `string`.

When the loop reaches the last element, you call `sb.charAt(i+1)` in the while which is placed before `i+1<sb.length()` so it will be always executed.

What you need to do is to swap the two conditions in the `while` loop: `while(i+1<sb.length() && sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1) && i+1<sb.length())
```

In this line, `sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1)` is evaluated before `i+1<sb.length()`, which means that you check that a following character exists only after you try to retrieve it.
Swap the two conditions, so that the check is performed before.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of bounds is generally caused when you are referencing an index that doesn't exist. Also remember that the index count starts from 0 not 1. On the last loop `sb.charAt(i+1)` would be `7 + 1 = 8`, which doesn't exist since your upper boundary is  `sb.Length()`, to fix this just make your upper boundary `for(int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i++)`

Comment: If you don't swap the order of checks in the `while` loop, this will still throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The index goes out of bounds because of the `i+1`

The `for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)` makes i vary from 0 to `length - 1` due to the `less than` symbol.

This is correct because a String or `N` characters will start at index 0 and finish at index `N-1`.

When you do `i+1` in the `for` loop, when it reaches the last character at index `i`, `i+1` goes out of the character array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as mentioned in the comments, is the `while` loop - so you should first check `i + 1 < sb.length()` and *then* check `sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)`.

Also - two other things:

- Remove the `println` statement as this makes it not compile
- No point returning an `int` (and hardcoded to 0), so change it to `String`

Example:

```
static String alternatingCharacters(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            while (i + 1 < sb.length() && sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)) {
                sb = sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/LWelL5)**

Answer (score 0):

Loop and delete will cause certainly `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("hello"); // length is 5
sb.deleteCharAt(2);                            // length is 4
```

And you still iterate until reaching 5, this will cause the exception

You can use Regex to build a clean solution:

```
"aaabbcccc".replaceAll("([a-z])\\1{1,}", "$1"); // the result will be abc
```